# Launching JADE on windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, agents-jade

i do not know how to launch JADE on eclipse. Can anyone tell me how to do it and how to run a small program on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will prefer you to run JADE using normal Notepad and manual compiling. 
However if you are bent on running it on Eclipse you need to add the jar files and the necessary libraries. Googling will help you in that..